# How to create typed file (d.ts) from typescript jspm project?

Tags: typescript, jspm, tsc, tsd

I write jspm project in TypeScript. It is working well and life is happy.

Now I want to create a single `d.ts` file for my module.

`tsc -d` with my `tsconfig.json` doesn't work as `tsc` cannot walk the imports from `jspm`.

`jspm` and `ts` (`plugin-typescript`) does not have that option either.

What should I do?